# How to get the desired output from a Hugging face LLM?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

**What I want:**
I want to generate synthetic reviews for E.g., Nurses

**What I'm using:**
I'm using open_llama_7b LLM from Hugging face to generate the reviews

**Prompt I'm using:**
"Your task is to generate 10 reviews written by nurses about how they feel about their workplace. Generate:"

**Result I'm getting:**
"I can’t write 271 words in two minutes.”\n“I have problems getting motivated to write.”\n“I have writing problems.”\n“Writing in a nursing journal is important because…”\n“I write a little because nursing is a profession.”\n“I don’t think it’s necessary to write and explain nursing and myself. “\n“To write, the environment has to be clean, quiet, and free of any distractions.”\n“Nursing and writing are important to me because of…”\n“I write to write, and if I am not motivated to write, I won’t write.”\n“A good time to write about nursing is after a busy day.”\n“I am writing this article to express my feelings about nursing.”\n"

**Result I want:**

1. "I love working at this facility. The staff is incredibly supportive and the patient population is diverse and interesting. The work-life balance is great, and there's always something new to learn."
2. "I feel like I'm constantly being asked to do more with less. The staffing levels are never adequate, and it's hard to provide quality care when you're overworked and understaffed."

**Code I'm using:**

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "openlm-research/open_llama_7b", device_map={"": 0}, load_in_4bit=True
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("openlm-research/open_llama_7b")

model_inputs = tokenizer(["Your task is to generate 10 reviews written by nurses about how they feel about their workplace. Generate:"], return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
generated_ids = model.generate(**model_inputs, do_sample=True,top_k=50, top_p=0.95, max_new_tokens = 1300)
tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
```

**I'm not sure what's the issue here:**

1. Is the model not powerful enough?
2. Am I using the wrong decoding method? (I read that default method is greedy that results in non-creative output, currently using Top-p in combination with Top-k)

**Ask**
What am I missing in the code to get the desired output?

So far I've tried guanaco 7b & open_llama_7b.

Comment: Food for thought: A model is as good as the data it's trained on. Models only seem to work magically in generating human-like wikipedia texts and actual chatbot responses because the model trained on wikipedia and chatbot responses.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, most probably someone will come along and close this question since Stackoverflow isn't an open-ended forum, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask